# Plotting multiple curves with a legend using subplot on matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, legend, subplot

I generate an animation with subplots using matplotlib, but for some subplots I want to include multiple curves with legends. I have not been able to make it work. My code looks like this:

```
load = np.rand(1000,24)
index = np.arange(24)
reward1 = np.rand(1000)
reward2 = np.rand(1000)
reward3 = np.rand(1000)
Z = np.arange(1000)
reward1 = np.vstack((Z,reward1))
reward2 = np.vstack((Z,reward2))
reward3 = np.vstack((Z,reward3))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,9))
fig.tight_layout()
lines = []
for nd, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    if nd == 0:
        l, = ax.plot(load[0,:],index)
    if nd == 1:
        l, = ax.plot(reward1[0], reward1[0])
    if nd == 2:
        l, = ax.plot(reward2[0], reward2[0])
    if nd == 3:
        l, = ax.plot(reward3[0], reward3[0])
    lines.append(l)

def run(it):
    for nd, line in enumerate(lines):
        if nd == 0:
            line.set_data(index,load[it,:])
        if nd == 1:
            line.set_data(reward1[..., :it])
        if nd == 2:
            line.set_data(reward2[..., :it])
        if nd == 3:
            line.set_data(reward3[..., :it])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, frames=1000, interval=30, blit=True)
ani.save('figure.mp4')
plt.show()
```

That creates an animation with 4 subplots. I'd like the reward curves to be on the same subplot with the corresponding legends. And of course, load and reward are not random, but I added that to show exactly what they are: numpy arrays.

To generate legends I have used this code:

```
plt.figure()
na1, = plt.plot(reward1)
na2, = plt.plot(reward2)
na3, = plt.plot(reward3)
plt.legend((na1,na2,na3),('Reward 1','Reward2','Reward 3'))
plt.show()
```

I was trying to integrate the two pieces of two code, but I have been unsuccessful. So, is there an easy way to do what I want?

Comment: could you add some example data for load and reward?

Comment: I've done so. I have edited the question and included what load and reward are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer**

What about adding the following line (e.g. after the loop in which you plot the lines):

```py
axes.flatten()[0].legend(handles=lines, labels=["index", "reward1", "reward2", "reward3"])
```

You need to pass your line instances as handles to the legend function to include lines from other subplots.

**Edit**

The following code works for me. Note, that I modified your example a bit to make it run. You should probably also have a look into the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) for more details on how to place and modify the legend. I inserted the legend code below your plotting loop. There are two alternatives to either draw one legend for all lines or one legend per line.

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
load = np.random.randn(1000, 24)
index = np.arange(24)
reward1 = np.random.randn(1000)
reward2 = np.random.randn(1000)
reward3 = np.random.randn(1000)
Z = np.arange(1000)
reward1 = np.vstack((Z, reward1))
reward2 = np.vstack((Z, reward2))
reward3 = np.vstack((Z, reward3))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 9))
fig.tight_layout()

axes = axes.flatten()

lines = []
for nd, ax in enumerate(axes):
    if nd == 0:
        l, = ax.plot(index, load[0, :], label="index")
    if nd == 1:
        l, = ax.plot(reward1[0], reward1[1], label="reward1")
    if nd == 2:
        l, = ax.plot(reward2[0], reward2[1], label="reward2")
    if nd == 3:
        l, = ax.plot(reward3[0], reward3[1], label="reward3")
    lines.append(l)

# Legend
# Have one legend on axes[0] for all lines
axes[0].legend(handles=lines, loc=1)

# Legend alternative
# Have one legend per axes for one line each
# for ax in axes:
#     ax.legend()

def init():
    return lines

def run(it):
    for nd, line in enumerate(lines):
        if nd == 0:
            line.set_data(index, load[it, :])
        if nd == 1:
            line.set_data(reward1[0, :it], reward1[1, :it])
        if nd == 2:
            line.set_data(reward2[0, :it], reward2[1, :it])
        if nd == 3:
            line.set_data(reward3[0, :it], reward3[1, :it])
    return lines

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, run, frames=np.arange(1000), interval=30, blit=True,
    init_func=init
)
ani.save('figure.mp4')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? It's generating a legend, but I haven't been able to pass the data from the lines to the legend object. So, it only displays one curve with two legends.

Comment: @Schach21 I hope my edited answer makes the legend part more clear. Otherwise, I am not sure if I really understood your problem. As you say "pass the data from the lines to the legend object", makes not too much sense to me. A legend is drawn passing *line instances* as handels and *labels* for the text. Modifying the *data* underlying the lines has no effect for the legend. If you want to change the legend (e.g. change the labels), you need to delete the old one and redraw it. Besides that, something wrong in the animation part could have messed up the figure.